# How to place the Hybrunner object in order to speed up the code

Tags: c#, hybridizer

What is the best way to separate the creation of the wrapped function and the running of it?

The following code will compile

```
public class TestHybRunnerPosition
{
    public void Function()
    {
        HybRunner runner = HybRunner.Cuda();

        dynamic wrapped = runner.Wrap(new TestHybRunnerPosition());

        wrapped.RunGPUCode();
    }

    [EntryPoint]
    void RunGPUCode()
    {
        //Do stuff
    }
}
```

However (I understand), this means there is a significant overhead to wrap the code every time Function() is called.
In order to reduce this overhead I decided to move the Hybrunner and make it a field in the class:-

```
public class TestHybRunnerPosition
{
    HybRunner runner;
    public TestHybRunnerPosition()
    {
        runner = HybRunner.Cuda();
    }
    public void Function()
    {
        dynamic wrapped = runner.Wrap(new TestHybRunnerPosition());
        wrapped.RunGPUCode();
    }
    …
}
```

This leads to a compile error:-

**[ERROR] : Exception in Hybridizer Main: 0X606A : Enum 
System.Security.SecurityRuleSet underlying type System.Byte not supported**

However, the following code does compile but crashes visual studio when it is run…

```
public class TestHybRunnerPosition
{
    dynamic wrapped;
    public TestHybRunnerPosition()
    {
        HybRunner runner = HybRunner.Cuda();
        wrapped = runner.Wrap(new TestHybRunnerPosition());
    }
    public void Function()
    {            
        wrapped.RunGPUCode();
    }
  …   
  }
```

Any idea how I might better proceed?

Comment: The first proposition with `HybRunner` as a field could work, but you need to specify that its contents does not go on the GPU. You may do this by adding a `HybridizerIgnore` attribute on the `runner` field.